# How to stop syncing read status on Outlook (MAC)

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook, sync, exchange

how to make MS Outlook 2010 on MAC not sync read/unread status of emails with the server. The problem comes when user A reads an e-mail, user B will receive it as a read mail, which is not good.
Is this client or server setting and where I can find it?
Thank you!

Comment: If this inbox is for something like `support@example.com` where multiple people will be checking the emails, you should really look into a helpdesk solution instead of inbox setup. While this does not directly answer your question, it may help open possibilities for best practices with a support environment. What is the email used for?

Comment: Exactly as you assumed, it's support mail address and several people are reading it. Since I need quick solution, I think that making read status stay on the readers device/client will be the best solution for the moment. What do you suggest?

Comment: Instead of using the Read flag since that is pretty much unavoidable, I would suggest using Categories. If someone else is working on an issue, change the category of the email to a different color. This way you won't have two people working on the same ticket. If you're a small office, look into making the category color for each person different. You should look into Open Source Support Ticket software or something like zendesk.